# Change DynamicResource Color Value during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

My goal is to define style in a Base theme, and be able to override certain values in a Custom theme by loading them on top of each other using `ResourceDictionary`. I have been able to get it to work with some properties but not others apparently due to [Freezable Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx), Colors is one that is not working. I thought changing the Color value in the ResourceDictionary would work but it is not:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryBackgroundColor}">
```

Base\Base.xaml:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBackgroundColor" Color="{DynamicResource Color_Base}"/>
```

Base\Colors.xaml:

```
<Color x:Key="Color_Base">Red</Color>
```

Custom\Colors.xaml:

```
<Color x:Key="Color_Base">Blue</Color>
```

Theme.cs:

```
foreach (ResourceDictEntry rde in changeList)
{
    Application.Current.Resources
               .MergedDictionaries
               .ElementAt(rde.dicIndex)[rde.key] = rde.value;
}
```

The code appears to work fine when I step through I am seeing the MergedDictionary entry for `Color_Base` be changed from Red `#FFFF0000` to Blue `#FF0000FF`.

However, my Grid whose Background is bound to the DynamicResource `PrimaryBackgroundColor` is not being changed from Red to Blue.

There are no errors shown in Snoop; the Grid.Background value shows PrimaryBackgroundColor as Red (#FFFF0000).

What am I missing? How can I change my Color value during runtime?

*For full code here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/dirte/773e6baf9a678e7632e6*

EDIT:

This looks to be the most relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17791735/1992193 but I thought the whole point of styles was to define it in one place and have everything use it without having to modify every xaml/code behind? What is the best solution?

I know one solution is to simply copy the entire base theme into a custom theme and only load which theme you want, but then it requires every property being managed across every theme file which is undesired.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to work out a solution by simply combining all the resource dictionary files into a single resource dictionary in code and applying the final combined resource dictionary.

```
public static void ChangeTheme(string themeName)
{
    string desiredTheme = themeName;    
    Uri uri;
    ResourceDictionary resourceDict;
    ResourceDictionary finalDict = new ResourceDictionary();

    // Clear then load Base theme
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
    themeName = "Base";
    foreach (var themeFile in Util.GetDirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(ThemeFolder, themeName)).GetFiles())
    {
        uri = new Uri(Util.GetPath(Path.Combine(ThemeFolder, themeName + @"\" + themeFile.Name)));
        resourceDict = new ResourceDictionary { Source = uri };
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in resourceDict)
        {
            finalDict.Add(de.Key, de.Value);
        }
    }
    // If all you want is Base, we are done
    if (desiredTheme == "Base")
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(finalDict);
        return;
    }

    // Now load desired custom theme, replacing keys found in Base theme with new values, and adding new key/values that didn't exist before
    themeName = desiredTheme;
    bool found;
    foreach (var themeFile in Util.GetDirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(ThemeFolder, themeName)).GetFiles())
    {
        uri = new Uri(Util.GetPath(Path.Combine(ThemeFolder, themeName + @"\" + themeFile.Name)));
        resourceDict = new ResourceDictionary { Source = uri };
        foreach (DictionaryEntry x in resourceDict)
        {
            found = false;
            // Replace existing values
            foreach (DictionaryEntry z in finalDict)
            {
                if (x.Key.ToString() == z.Key.ToString())
                {
                    finalDict[x.Key] = x.Value;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Otherwise add new values
            if (!found)
            {
                finalDict.Add(x.Key, x.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    // Apply final dictionary
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(finalDict);
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryBackgroundColor}">
```

Base.xaml:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBackgroundColor" Color="{DynamicResource Color_Base}"/>
```

Base\Colors.xaml:

```
<Color x:Key="Color_Base">Red</Color>
```

Custom\Colors.xaml:

```
<Color x:Key="Color_Base">Blue</Color>
```